# Pickling of enum with functional API throws error

Tags: python, enums, pickle, cpython

I want to create a enum from a list of variables and then pickle it. I use the functional constructor. This should be done inside a class that is loaded in different sub-classes.

I got it to work for a specific object with the qualname, but did not find a generalizable solution for usage in different classes. In the example below I would like to use both `outer_class_enum1` and `outer_class_enum2`. I am wondering if this is possible with the functional API?

```
import pickle
import enum


class InnerClass:
    def __init__(self):
        classes = ["dog", "cat", "cow"]
        self.list_enum = enum.Enum(
            "list_enum",
            classes,
            start=0,
            module=__name__,
            qualname="outer_class_enum1.inner_class.list_enum",  # works with 
            specific object
            # qualname="self.inner_class.list_enum",   # does not work
            # qualname="InnerClass.list_enum",   # does not work
        )

class OuterClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inner_class = InnerClass()


# **************************************************************************
# Enum variant 1 - works
# **************************************************************************
outer_class_enum1 = OuterClass()
with open("test.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(outer_class_enum1, f)  # works

# **************************************************************************
# Enum variant 2 - error
# **************************************************************************
outer_class_enum2 = OuterClass()
with open("test.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(outer_class_enum2, f)  # throws error
```

Also see the original question: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/106959

Comment: You'll need to add a custom `__reduce_ex__` to `InnerClass`.

Comment: Is your enum actually different in every instance of `InnerClass` ?

Comment: The enum is the same for every instance of `InnerClass` in a specific version of the code. 

The list `classes` is read from a file and does change for different use cases.

Comment: Can you post an example file that enums would be built with?